# Why is list changed after encoding and decoding using pickle in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, python-3.8

I have a list in one computer(Linux, Python3.8.5) and I want to transfer the list to another computer.

I want to use pickle to handle this list:

```
[[('MMH', 1)],
 [('MMH', 1)],
 [('MMH', 1)],
 [('MMH', 1)],
 [('MMH', 1), ('MMH+NO2-v3', 330), ('MMH', 427), ('MMH+NO2-v3', 916), ('MMH', 932)],
 [('MMH', 1)],
 ...
 [('MMH', 1), ('MMH+NO2-v2', 1048)],
 [('MMH', 1), ('MMH+NO2-v2', 271), ('MMH', 389), ('MMH+NO2-v2', 484), ('CH3-N-NH2', 524), ('MMH+NO2-v2', 728), ('MMH', 787)]]
```

The length of this List is **1910**.

I saved the list in a file named SpecTrac.txt.

```
Ft = open("SpecTrac.txt", 'wb')   
pickle.dump(List, Ft)             
Ft.close()
```

And read that file on another computer(Linux, Python3.8.5).

```
ftname = "SpecTrac.txt"
f =  open(ftname, 'rb')
Rec2 = pickle.load(f)
```

And the length of Rec2 is only **79**.

I have no idea about what's going wrong.

---

### My debug process:

**1. pickle a 22 elements list:**

it Works! no problems

the list is:

> ```
> [['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1), ('MMH-NO2', 92), ('MMH', 222)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)],
> ['a', ('MMH', 1)]]
> ```

2. pickle a 222 elements list:

   An error raise

> UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x03'.

3. pickle a 556 elements list:

   Wrong results!

   The second computer only get a 112 elements list.

Nothing wrong when pickle and unpickle in the same computer.

Comment: That sounds strange, are you sure you unpickled the correct file? Do the file sizes match? What happens when you unpickle on the same computer?

Comment: Can you share the full `List` somewhere for us to reproduce?

Comment: @timgeb. I double checked the file. The file sizes match correctly. All is well on the same computer.

Comment: The file is named `.txt` even though it's binary, not text. Is it possible that the file was corrupted by being transferred to the other computer over a network in text mode? Do the file hashes match?

Comment: @yvesonline Do you mean the pickled file "SpecTrac.txt" or the List? It's a long list with 1910 elememts.

Comment: @timgeb I open the file in VIM. The binary files on different computer look different.

Comment: You could try reducing the size of the list to see if the problem still occurs; a [mcve] might not need all 1910 elements.

Comment: @kaya3 My debug process Updated

Comment: @kaya3 The sha1sum is different, but the file size is the same.

Comment: In that case the file was corrupted in transit.

Comment: so if you would write your list to a text file, how big is it ? maybe you hit some boundaries...

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks for you guidance! I download the binary file from a supercomputing center and analyze the data on my PC. Maybe, I need contact the administer.

Comment: @user3732793 It's about 320MB, but the reading process is so complicated.

Comment: looks like more than 100MB can be a problem from other posts. Thought pickles is the wrong solution for you. Even for any queue system. Maybe best is good old file transfer in that case